# Tweenlight Fade with Sprite Graphic

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, gsap

I have a sprite which I draw a white rectangle on (below) and want to use `TweenLite` to fade the sprite in and out but it either shows or hides the the sprite. Animating the sizing such as `scaleX` works fine just the alpha. Any ideas?

```
private function Draw():void {          
   panel.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF);
   panel.graphics.drawRect(0,0,367,135);
   panel.graphics.endFill();
}

public function FadeIn():void {
   trace("fadeIn");
   panel.alpha=0;
   TweenLite.to(panel, 2, {alpha:100});
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate little bit more may be by providing some more code.

Comment: found the issue, alpha was 100 not 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the issue, alpha was 100 not 1 therefore tweenlite was trying to set the alpha to 100 on each update causing hte flickering